# Where to learn IE6 css issues

Tags: html, css

I have created html/css for modern browsers (IE7 and above, firefox, etc) and am good at it.

When I look into my html/css with ie6, there is always something wrong.

The fixes I create for it are usually ie6-specific (no problem though), and I usually don't know exactly what caused the issue (or how I fixed it sometimes).

I want to become more knowledgeable about css (old and new).

What book/website do you recommend?

Comment: Forget those punks, don't waste your time. The future is now.

Comment: @zzzzBov Link or it didn't happen :)

Comment: @alex i was misinformed, and therefor have removed the offending comment. I have found no evidence that microsoft will drop support for IE6 any sooner than they will drop support for windows XP. That doesn't mean developers have to continue to support users who are using outdated software. Let extreme backwards compatibility be something you get paid extra for, rather than a standard feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend http://www.quirksmode.org

They say that:
'QuirksMode.org is the prime source for browser compatibility information on the Internet.'

Answer (score 2):

[Explorer Exposed! on Position is Everything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) is my favourite resource.

Answer (score 1):

To learn about browser quirks: [Quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are targeting China, don't even bother. It's a headache and the w3c now states that only 4.8% of users are using 6, and that is going down fast.

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: That is not the W3C - and those stats are skewed towards web professionals. `W3Schools is a website for people with an interest for web technologies. These people are more interested in using alternative browsers than the average user. The average user tends to use Internet Explorer, since it comes preinstalled with Windows. Most do not seek out other browsers.`

Comment: There are so many corporate setups using XP Pro with IE6 as their SOE, it's still not feasible to completely ignore IE6.